# How to write your own legally binding will

Tags: contract-law, wills

As a laymen, without seeking a professional lawyer.

How can one write a will that is legally binding and will be respected after your death.

I know you need witnesses. Maybe even a notary would be nice. I dont know. Just to cover your bases.

Comment: I'm afraid this is too broad for a Stack Exchange question.  It varies among all the world's jurisdictions, and in each one it would take at least a short book to explain the process with any reasonable completeness.  However, there is commercial software available in many jurisdictions to help.

Answer (score 1):

A quick response is "ask your attorney" (which defeats the purpose of the question). The first thing to do is get an elementary understanding of the law, perhaps by studying the questions and answers on Law SE. Since wills are not contracts, you would learn that contract law is not an important issue (and eventually you could learn how it does become relevant). The biggest impediment to self-drafted contracts and wills is the author's lack of basic understanding of law. Let's say that a reading list for basics of law is a complex separate question.

Second thing is to understand the importance of jurisdiction: it depends on what country and state you are in. There are specific requirements in each jurisdiction. I will use Washington state for my analysis. Find the [laws governing wills](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=11.12&full=true) in your state. In fact, you should not focus just on wills, you should focus on [probate](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=11), because somebody has to be able to actually do what the will says, so you should consider if you're set your successor up to fail.
The third thing to do is get a book relevant for the state – though here are probably many online sources (here's [one starter](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/how-write-will.html), which will eventually direct you to [this](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/what-will-wont-do-29767.html) that includes the advice to not try to write your spouse out of the estate in a community property state). Such sources will (hopefully) explain what the law requires.

Comment: You should add that some jurisdictions require a lawyer to be involved for the will to be valid.

Comment: Where would that be?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response.  I appreciate your answer.  I do just so happen to live in Washington state, myself, so this is very applicable.  Washington requires no lawyer and no notary, and in fact a will need not even be typed. You do need your witnesses to the signing though.